# Format a large double to show four significant digits

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, significant-digits

I have a large double, for example `345533345.8993`. But, the double is calculated with measured values who have an accuracy of only 4 digits. Hence, in my result I want to show the number of digits that are guaranteed, something like `3455 * 10^5`.

I can write something myself, but I'm looking for a standard way to do this. Is there a way to render this significant measured number?

Comment: Yes. I see it is not possible in standard formatting. The other answers write functions themselves too. I am very sorry not to have seen that. But there so many answers about formatting to the correct number of digits behind the decimal dots, I did not see it. I will write something myself for my specific situation. And again sorry for my first comment.

Comment: Let's not be so sure the built in formatters don't help. Is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that exact 'E somenumber' format is what is used mostly in such situations. Sorry I could not find it.

Comment: No need to apologise. Acquaint yourself with the MSDN page I linked to, there's a wide range of possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

```
double large = 345533345.8993;
Console.WriteLine("large double showing four sig figs: {0:####E0}", large);
```

displays 3455E5

Answer (score 3):

You can use *number*.ToString("G4") where "G" is a "General number format" returning "the most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation" and "4" is the number of significant digits ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)).

`345533345.8993.ToString("G4")` returns "3.455E+08".

There's also the exponential ("E") format specifier and various other possibilities. See MSDN.